# Advanced Installer – Don’t overwrite file when update but remove the file when uninstall

Tags: windows-installer, installation, advanced-installer, uninstallation

I’m using Advanced Installer 14.6 and have following requirement for my application’s uninstaller:-

1)  If user does an uninstall, it completely removes away the application’s folder from Program Files, including all files in the folder.

2)  If the Update process is invoked, then save the config file in application’s folder and update all other files.

I have tried numerous options to achieve this but all in vain. Setting condition UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE to “Do not overwrite existing file” for config file, supposed to work when we don’t want the file to be overwritten during upgrade and remove when uninstall. But setting this condition removes file when uninstall and overwrites the file with new one when update.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An upgrade installation consists in two parts:

- the uninstall of the old product version
- the installation of the new product version

To back up some files during an upgrade, you need to handle it through a custom action.

There will be two custom actions, first custom action will back up the files before the old version being removed and another custom action that will restore the backuped files after the installation of the upgraded version.

Answer (score 1):

As Phil mentioned, in the upgrade package using the property UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE is useless. You should use instead the property [OLDPRODUCTS](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/properties.html), read more in the following articles from [Advanced Installer's user guide.](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-keep-file.html)

Also, if that file is a standard XML or INI file you can use the [search support](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-XML-locator.html) from Advanced Installer to read the entries customized by your users and [write them back in the config file](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-import-edit-xml-file.html) written by the new version. This way you can also easily include new updates in this file with a new release. (*not just keep using the original file installed by the first version*)

Comment: The 'OLDPRODUCTS' condition functions flawlessly for files in the root directory, but how can I avoid overwriting files in a subfolder? Setting the overwrite condition for both files and the subfolder to 'OLDPRODUCTS' do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should define what "upgrade" actually means. Your post implies that you are doing a Windows Installer major upgrade, but you haven't said, most importantly, where the upgrade is sequenced. If it is sequenced "early", such as just after InstallInitialize, then it is effectively still an uninstall of the old product followed by an install of the upgrade, so you lose the config file. The way people deal with the situation you describe is to sequence the upgrade (the RemoveExistingProducts call) towards the end of the upgrade (such as after InstallExecute and just before InstallFinalize) which results in the upgrade being installed over the existing product, and file overwrite rules are followed, in particular this one:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

which is that modified data files will not be overwritten. So if that config file has been updated after it was installed then it will not be overwritten. So there's no need to do anything to preserve the file, assuming you want to preserve any updated settings. If you still want to copy the file before the upgrade, use the property that is set when the upgrade install - the docs aren't clear on this but it seems to be the result property you set in the Upgrade Action tab.

It's not clear to me what you are doing with "Setting condition UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE to “Do not overwrite existing file” " . The UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE  property is not set in the upgrade install. It is set in the older product when it is being uninstalled so that the older product knows if it is being upgraded or not. It can't be used in the actual incoming upgrade setup because it's not set to anything.